# Applying CSS associated with ID of one element to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wish to apply css associated with #originalTable to #newTable.

Most of the style will be associated with class .general, however, it is that style specific to the ID which has got me stumped. #originalTable will remain in the DOM, so I can't just move the ID.  I would rather not manually iterate over every element to associate the styles since most of the style will typically be applied by class .general.  I also do not wish to duplicate the rules in my style sheet for either #newTable or some new class applied to #newTable.

How can this be accomplished?  Thank you

CSS

```
.general {//some CSS}
.general thead {//some CSS}
.general thead th {//some CSS}

#originalTable {//some CSS}
#originalTable thead {//some CSS}
#originalTable thead th  {//some CSS}
```

HTML

```
<table id="originalTable" class="general">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>
            <th>H2</th>
            <th>H3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>B1</th>
            <th>B2</th>
            <th>B3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="newTable" class="general">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>
            <th>H2</th>
            <th>H3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>B1</th>
            <th>B2</th>
            <th>B3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you can modify the HTML and CSS, then just use a class name instead of an ID to specify the CSS.  Then, you can add the class name to as many objects as you want to have that style.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "I wish to apply css associated with #originalTable to #newTable.". Could you clarify? Is JavaScript dynamically changing the page or anything?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but it seems to me that you could do something like `#originalTable, #newtable {//some CSS}`.

Comment: I am creating a jQuery plugin which creates some new DOM.  I want to give the user the ability to style the original #newTable either by targeting the ID or class as they see fit, and then having the plugin style the new DOM similarly.

Comment: Then maybe you should use a class instead of the ID and then use jQuery to get the class off of the old table and add it to the new DOM tables.

Comment: @RachelG,  If need be, I will just create the plugin to only work with style targeted by a class.  Was hoping there was an easy way, however, to allow it also to work with style targeted by an ID.

Answer (score 2):

```
#originalTable, #newTable {//some CSS}
#originalTable thead, #newTable thead {//some CSS}
#originalTable thead th, #newTable thead th  {//some CSS}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Note my last stated objective: I also do not wish to duplicate the rules in my style sheet for either #newTable or some new class applied to #newTable.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the code to this:

CSS:

```
.general {//some CSS}
.general thead {//some CSS}
.general thead th {//some CSS}

.originalTable {//some CSS}
.originalTable thead {//some CSS}
.originalTable thead th  {//some CSS}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="general">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>
            <th>H2</th>
            <th>H3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>B1</th>
            <th>B2</th>
            <th>B3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="general originalTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>H1</th>
            <th>H2</th>
            <th>H3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>B1</th>
            <th>B2</th>
            <th>B3</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad.  See my comment under my original post why this is not desired.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't help you man. I don't get the exact point of your question.

Comment: Appreciate the help even though it didn't provide a solution.  I should have said why I wish to do so.  I am trying to create a plugin which will take the CSS added to an element by the user, and apply it to another element, and I don't have control how the user will style the element.

Comment: In my point of view, you should fix the flow through one way, then you can make it done. Either define css classes by **#ID** or **.CLASS**. I myself prefer the second way, because you can iterate the value of the `"class"` attribute and see how many classes are assigned to your element which you can't do such a thing by using the first way. There are many libraries that support this way. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all tables have a CSS property, use:

```
table {
    //some CSS code
}
```

If you want all "general" tables to have some property, use:

```
.general { 
    //some CSS code
}
```

If you want certain "special" tables to have an additional property, use:

```
.special { 
    //some CSS code 
}
```

If you want just 1 specific table to have a property, use:

```
#newTable { 
    //some CSS code
}
```

If you want 2 tables to have a property, use:

```
#newTable, #oldTable {
    //some CSS code
}
```

Note that last one can be further specified. For example `#newTable head, #oldTable head`.

Then you could have

```
<table id="newTable" class="general special">
    //some HTML code
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel.  Similar to the other given answers, this doesn't meet all my objectives regarding duplicating my style sheet rules.  Reason for this objective is that the new table is being dynamically generated, and I do not have control over the overriding CSS.

Comment: Yeah. I wrote before I saw your jQuery task. So you have no control over the `originalTable` css configuration?

Comment: Yes, I don't have control over the orginalTable CSS.  I should have spelled that out in my original post.  If need be, I tell the users of the plugin that style may only be applied by targeting the class, and not the ID.